# Use SSL Certificate from SiteGround for AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a Next application running with NGINX on AWS EC2 Instance and I need to add an SSL Certificate to it. My domain is registered on SiteGround and I already linked the domain with the next application running on EC2.

I already have an SSL Certificate on SiteGround. Is there a way I can use this SSL Certificate on SiteGround with the application on EC2?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your SSL certificate from SiteGround by going to Site Tools -> Security -> SSL Manager, selecting the 3 dot menu under actions and clicking View Certificate.

On the AWS side, go to Certificate Manager, click the import button and paste the 3 values provided by SiteGround.

I was using the certificate for an elastic beanstalk environment, so I just added a listener for port 443 with the certificate to the load balancer for my environment.

Answer (score 0):

While importing I was getting

```
Failed to import certificate There was a problem when importing your certificate.
```

But found out that I had to copy

```
Siteground values       ->     AWS values
Certificate (CRT)       ->        Certificate body

Private Key (KEY)       ->        Certificate private key  
 
Certificate Authority   ->        Certificate chain - optional 
Bundle (CABUNDLE)
```

I wasn't doing the third one.